# Video 100% width and height

Tags: html, css, html5-video, fullscreen

I have a video, and I want it to FILL 100% of the width, and 100% of the height. And keep the aspect ratio.

Is it possible that it at least fills 100% for both? And if a bit of the video has to be out of the screen to keep the aspect ratio, that doesn't matter.

HTML:

```
    <video preload="auto" class="videot" id="videot" height="100%" preload>
    <source src="BESTANDEN/video/tible.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    <object data="BESTANDEN/video/tible.mp4" height="1080">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="autoplay" value="false" >
        <param name="loop" value="false" >
    </object>
```

CSS:

```
 .videof, .videot {
    width: 100%    !important;
    height: 100%   !important;
 }
```

Comment: Try using `max-width` and `max-height` instead.  By setting the `width` and `height` to 100%, you might be stretching the video to fit those exact dimensions.

Comment: I used min-width and min-height instead, because max-height and width didn't work. But now the video is full screen, but there is still a max on the width; the video size. And It won't become bigger...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use Javascript to dynamically set the height to 100% of the window and then center it using a negative left margin based on the ratio of video width to window width.

http://jsfiddle.net/RfV5C/

```
var $video  = $('video'),
    $window = $(window); 

$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $window.height();
    $video.css('height', height);

    var videoWidth = $video.width(),
        windowWidth = $window.width(),
    marginLeftAdjust =   (windowWidth - videoWidth) / 2;

    $video.css({
        'height': height, 
        'marginLeft' : marginLeftAdjust
    });
}).resize();
```

Comment: This does not fill both the width and height, if u enlarge the window size then it leaves whitespace. So not really an acceptable answer to his question.

Comment: If you resize the window, you need to call a function to change the video size. jQuery: `$( window ).resize(function() { console.log("run resize function again!");});`

Comment: seems like jquery, not javascript

Answer (score 119):

By checking other answers, I used object-fit in CSS:

```
video {
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

The object-fit CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

Value: fill

The replaced content is sized to fill the element’s content box: the object’s concrete object size is the element’s used width and height.

Comment: This distorts the video for me.

Comment: Can also use `object-fit: contain;` (Among other options)

Comment: This is simply the best solution! Should be marked as correct!

Comment: Be aware that this solution doesn't work for IE11 or Edge.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I've used object-fit: cover; for my needs, thanks !

Answer (score 40):

Easiest & Responsive.

```html
<video src="full.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>

<style>
    video {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: fill; // use "cover" to avoid distortion
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. As for actually filling 100% of both width and height. If you dont want distortion of video, use `object-fit:cover` instead.. but this is correct. no js needed, pure css

Answer (score 37):

If you're looking for the equivalent to `background-size: cover` for `video`.

```css
video {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

This will fill the container without distorting the video.

---

<sup>PS: I'm extending on [Leo Yu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39668310/6941627) here.</sup>

Comment: You're not extending Leo Yu's  answer. You're giving the correct answer. That answer distorts the video if the viewport size does not have exactly the same ratio as the video, whereas your answer crops the video without distorting it. I can't think of any case where a professional website would want a distorted background video, so your answer is far more useful. I'd remove that remark if I were you.

Answer (score 27):

```
video {
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: auto   !important;
}
```

Take a look here
http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: nevertheless, this was the solution I needed ;) thx for that tipp, and no !important was needed here.

Comment: One tip: add `object-fit: fill;` to the `video` tag. It will scretch to 100%. And keep width and height at 100%

Comment: After around two hours of experimenting, this did the trick. Thank you so much.

Comment: This answer, but I prefer `max-width` as it will contain large videos, but not distort low resolution ones (been working with a lot of archives lately)

Answer (score 11):

This works for me for video in a div container.

```css
.videoContainer 
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoContainer video 
{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Reference: http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/tutorials/html-5-full-screen-and-responsive-videos

Answer (score 6):

Put the video inside a parent div, and set all to 100% width & height with fill of cover. This will ensure the video isn't distorted and ALWAYS fills the div entirely.

```
.video-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video-wrapper video {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach would be to change the css as

```
.videot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I use JavaScript and CSS to accomplish this. The JS function needs to be called once on init and on window resize. Just tested in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<video width="1920" height="1080" controls>
    <source src="./assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JavaScript:

```
function scaleVideo() {
    var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    if (w/16 >= h/9) {
        vid.setAttribute('width', w);
        vid.setAttribute('height', 'auto');
    } else {
        vid.setAttribute('width', 'auto');
        vid.setAttribute('height', h);
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
video {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<style>
    .video{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;object-fit:cover}
  }
</style>
<video class= "video""
  disableremoteplayback=""
  mqn-lazyimage-video-no-play=""
  mqn-video-css-triggers="[{&quot;fire_once&quot;: true, &quot;classes&quot;: [&quot;.mqn2-ciu&quot;], &quot;from&quot;: 1, &quot;class&quot;: &quot;mqn2-grid-1--hero-intro-video-meta-visible&quot;}]"
  mqn-video-inview-no-reset="" mqn-video-inview-play="" muted="" playsinline="" autoplay>

<source src="https://github.com/Slender1808/Web-Adobe-XD/raw/master/Home/0013-0140.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great way to make the video fit a banner, you might need to tweak this a little for full screen but should be ok. 100% CSS.

```html
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

We tried with the below code & it works on Samsung TV, Chrome, IE11, Safari...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" >

        html,body {
          height: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0;
          padding:0;
        }

        video {
            width: 100vw; /*100% of horizontal viewport*/
            height:100vh; /*100% of vertical viewport*/
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <video preload="auto" class="videot" id="videot" preload>
            <source src="BESTANDEN/video/tible.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
            <object data="BESTANDEN/video/tible.mp4" height="1080">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <param name="autoplay" value="false" >
                <param name="loop" value="false" >
            </object>
        </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css for height

```
height: calc(100vh) !important;
```

This will make the video to have 100% vertical height available.

Answer (score 0):

There are other settings that go along with object-fit. i.e. from a full page video:

> object-fit: contain; overflow-clip-margin: content-box; overflow:
> clip; overflow-x: ; overflow-y: ;

You'll need to adjust it for you but maybe there's something there with "overflow-clip-margin" and "overflow:clip" that can further assist you in controlling or setting the clip to get fullscreen.

Answer (score -2):

I am new into all of this. Maybe you can just add/change this HTML code. Without need for CSS. It worked for me :)

```
width="100%" height="height"
```

Comment: Your eagerness to contribute to the community is appreciated but this is just wrong (the height attribute does not take "height" as a valid value).