# Video background in a middle of a header and footer divs tags

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
html, body {height: 100%; margin:0px !important;}

#header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;

    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}

#footer{
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

html

```
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="content">
    <video src="video.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

I want video in the `div` content, and that video fills the space `div` without that resolution of video is increased.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem?  What is happening with your current code?

Comment: Hi, I want video in the div content, And that video fills the space div without that resolution of video is increased.

Comment: Alfonso, I gathered that.  But what is your current code doing?  What have you tried?

Comment: I Put in the video tag the id content, but the video appears in full zoom, appears baddly, the control of video not appear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [video 100% width and hight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127763/video-100-width-and-hight)

Comment: Hi, with height and height on 100% appears looks like http://jsfiddle.net/jhonnynho/w1fnmLu8/

Comment: did you try `width:100%` and `height:auto`? you can also try vice-versa to see whats looks better

Comment: `controls="true"` Should show the controls. `true` just adds compitability, could also just say `controls`