# Is there a tag in the HTML video to make minimum height and width?

Tags: html

Is there a tag in the HTML video to make minimum height and width? I was wondering if it was possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127763/video-100-width-and-height

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by minimum? A video tag by default conforms to the dimensions of the video file. If your MP4 dimensions are 480x360 so too will your video tag so long as there's no styles assigning width or height.

Comment: minimum as in If a user makes their window smaller, the video will get smaller to a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use percentages within your dimensions. For example:

```html
<video width=10% height=10% autoplay controls loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[via w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height on your video tag like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```